# How to fix segmentation error in C programming?

Tags: c, fgets

I want to get the user input to open a txt file but I'm getting this compilation error called. `[1]    85501 segmentation fault` can someone help me with this? A sample input `2021-10-17`

Here's git repo https://github.com/anjula-sack/diary

```
    void DecryptEntry()
    {
      FILE *fptr;

      char filename[20];
      printf("Please enter the date of the entry you want to read, ex:2021-10-17\n");
      fscanf(stdin, " ");
      fgets(filename, 20, stdin);
    
      strcpy(filename, ".txt");
      printf("%s.txt", filename);
    
    
      if ((fptr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
      {
        printf("Error! the entry doesn't exist");
      }
    }
```

Comment: First of all use a *debugger* to catch the crash and locate when and where in your code it happens. Then also examine all variables to make sure they're alright. Also, a segmentation fault is a *run-time* error, a crash. Not a compilation error.

Comment: I'm new to this. I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: Look for a tutorial on your working environment. Many of them have built in debuggers.
you can use gdb as well.

Comment: What is your input? `fptr` is not declared. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. BTW, yor code doesn't make much sense, after `fgets(filename, 20, stdin)` you copy `".txt"` into `filename` which will overwrite the input you just entered, you probably want `strcat(filename, ".txt");`. And `segmentation fault` is not a compilation error but a runtime error.

Comment: The code you show is weird and nonsensical, but shouldn't really have anything that could lead to a run-time crash. I'll bet the crash actually happens in some other code. We really need a proper [mre]. And you really need to learn how to use a debugger. You should be able to find some tutorials online if you search around a little.

Comment: I added the git repo with the full code.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There is too much code in your repository and you don't tell us which input triggers the problem. You need to make a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of spamming multiple comments about minimal example, maybe actually cast your close votes and the OP will get that same message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the actual code from your github link, then you have this:

```
strcpy(filename, ".txt");

if ((fptr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
{
  printf("Error! the entry doesn't exist");
}

fgets(message, 100, fptr);
```

First of all the `strcpy` is nonsense since it overwrites the filename and replaces it with `".txt"`. Since that is never a valid file name, `fopen` will always fail. And when it fails, you print an error message but continue execution, so the next `fgets` call will cause the crash.

Fix this by allocating enough space for filename, replace `strcpy` (overwrite) with `strcat` (append) and do a `return` etc upon failing to open the file.

You could easily have found these bugs yourself by single-stepping through the function using a debugger.